# Docker for Windows, AspNetCore, and aspnet-webpack Hot Module

Tags: asp.net-core, npm, webpack, docker-for-windows, hot-module-replacement

I've recently converted my AspNetCore web application to use docker containers for local development and have run into trouble getting the npm module "aspnet-webpack" to work.

When I start the container, I get the following error:

`Microsoft.AspNetCore.NodeServices.HostingModels.NodeInvocationException: Webpack dev middleware failed because of an error while loading 'aspnet-webpack'. Error was: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat 'C:\ContainerMappedDirectories'`

Of course, if I comment out the below snippet of code, the error goes away, but I'd appreciate it if anyone has some advice on getting my webpack hot module to work:

```
app.UseWebpackDevMiddleware(new WebpackDevMiddlewareOptions
{
    HotModuleReplacement = true
});
```

Here's a simplified snippet of my DockerFile (hope I'm not missing anything):

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-aspnetcore-runtime-nanoserver-sac2016 AS base
# Pretend I install nodejs here or the image above already has it
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-sdk-nanoserver-1803 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["WebApp/WebApp.csproj", "WebApp/"]
RUN dotnet restore "WebApp/WebApp.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/WebApp"
RUN dotnet build "WebApp.csproj" -c Release -o /app

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "WebApp.csproj" -c Release -o /app

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "WebApp.dll"]
```

And a simplified snippet of my docker-compose.yml:

```
services:
  webapp:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}webapp
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: WebApp\Dockerfile
  environment:
    - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
    - ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+:80
  ports:
    - "53760:80"
  volumes:
    - ${APPDATA}/ASP.NET/Https:C:\Users\ContainerUser\AppData\Roaming\ASP.NET\Https:ro
    - ${APPDATA}/Microsoft/UserSecrets:C:\Users\ContainerUser\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\UserSecrets:ro
    - .\WebApp\node_modules:C:/app/node_modules
```

Notice that I tried mapping my node_modules from my local machine to the container to see if that'd help the hot module to find "aspnet-webpack."